# Is there a way to pivot a customer ID and a their most recent order dates?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot

I have a query that gives me all customer's and their last three order dates.

EX:

```
CustomerId DateOrdered
167 2006-09-16 01:25:38.060
167 2006-09-21 13:11:53.530
171 2006-08-31 15:19:22.543
171 2006-09-01 13:30:54.013
171 2006-09-01 13:34:36.483
178 2006-09-04 11:36:19.983
186 2006-09-05 12:50:27.153
186 2006-09-05 12:51:08.513
```

I want to know if there is a way for me to pivot it to display like this:

```
[CustomerId]    [Most Recent] [Middle] [Oldest]
'167'   '2006-09-21 13:11:53.530'   '2006-09-16 01:25:38.060'   'NULL'
'171'    '2006-09-01 13:34:36.483'   '2006-09-01 13:30:54.013'   '2006-08-31 15:19:22.543'
'178'   '2006-09-04 11:36:19.983'   NULL    NULL
'186'   '2006-09-05 12:51:08.513'   '2006-09-05 12:50:27.153'   NULL
```

Comment: What do you mean by "middle" date?

Comment: @dave, the date that's not the oldest and not the newest. The columns don't necessarily need names, I just need them to be ordered.

Comment: Ah -- "...last 3 orders"  If only I could read :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;WITH YourQuery As
(
SELECT CustomerId, DateOrdered,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY DateOrdered DESC) AS RN
FROM Orders
)
select [CustomerId],
MAX(CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN DateOrdered END) AS  [Most Recent] ,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN=2 THEN DateOrdered END) AS  [Middle] ,
MAX(CASE WHEN RN=3 THEN DateOrdered END) AS  [Oldest] 
FROM YourQuery
WHERE RN<=3
GROUP BY [CustomerId]
```

Comment: Oooh, a CASE in a MAX.  Very clever.   I like it.

Comment: Awesome. the dates were backward, but I was able to fix that. Can you explain what's happening?

Comment: I think I get it. That is very clever. Am I right in thinking that I could pivot on RN from the CTE and end up with the same thing?

Comment: The 1st part will assign a rownumber  ordered by `DateOrdered DESC` with 1 the most recent, 2 middle etc. This row numbering is restarted for each customer (as it is partitioned by customerid). In the 2nd part without `group by` there would be max 3 rows per CustomerId with 0 or 1 rows for any specific CustomerId/RowNumber combination. Grouping by  CustomerId will collapse it to 1 record per CustomerId. Using `MAX(CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN DateOrdered END)` will put the value in the RN=1 row (if present) to that column or NULL if not present. Using 'MIN' would work too as with 1 match MAX = MIN

Comment: @dave - Not at all. It depends what indexes are there. It is often the most efficient way of solving this sort of issue as it avoids the need to access the table more than once and so reduces I/O. And in this case the OP already has a query returning the last 3 orders per customer, @scottm you mean using standard SQL Server Pivot syntax? - Yes it should work with that fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: Not Tested**

I think you're looking for something like this.  The specific joins and where clause may need some work, but basically your just joining the table back on itself to get one date each time.

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMERID, C.DATEORDERED, C2.DATEORDERED, C3.DATEORDERED
FROM CUSTOMER C
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C2 ON C.CUSTOMERID = C2.CUSTOMERID
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C3 ON C.CUSTOMERID = C3.CUSTOMERID
WHERE C.DATEORDERED = MAX(C.DATEORDERED)
AND C2.DATEORDERED < C.DATEORDERED AND 
    (C3.DATEORDERED IS NULL OR C2.DATEORDERED >     C3.DATEORDERED)
```