# select last three dates and display in one row per id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table of **sales records** where a particular sales order can be updated **multiple** times. I need to get the **3** most recent updates, and display them in a **single row.**

I have looked at the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527527/sql-server-get-values-of-top-three-records-and-display-in-one-row-per-person) but am battling to get that to work for me.

EDIT:

Here is an example of the original data:

```
order no   DateTime
4774875 1
4774875 2
4774875 3
4944839 3
4944839 2
4944839 1
5245283 1
5245283 2
5245283 3
5268774 3
5268774 2
5268774 1
5268813 1
5268813 2
5268813 3
```

And the ideal output:

```
Order no    Date1   Date2   Date3
4774875 1   2   3
4944839 1   2   3
5245283 1   2   3
5268774 1   2   3
5268813 1   2   3
```

Comment: Can you post your table schema and some test data along with the expected output?

Comment: Yup; still figuring out how to edit those nicely; the 1,2,3 displays it without having to present a full date.

Comment: Looks like you need to use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @Magnus can you provide a code example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to pivot a customer ID and a their most recent order dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401218/is-there-a-way-to-pivot-a-customer-id-and-a-their-most-recent-order-dates)

Comment: @tithij There are plenty of code examples on the page i linked to.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, thanks for finding that, that has worked really well for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this . [Here is the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d81e/10)

**Note:** this is as per your OP, from which I thought you needed `1 2 3` in a `single col`. You may need a `PIVOT to get them in 3 separate columns`.

```
SELECT T1.oid, REPLACE( (SELECT T2.d AS [data()]
            FROM T T2
            WHERE T2.oid = T1.oid
            ORDER BY T2.d
            FOR XML PATH('')),' ', ' : ') x           
FROM (SELECT oid,d, rank() over(partition by oid order by d desc) rk 
FROM T) T1
WHERE rk <=3
GROUP BY oid

--Results (you can remove : if you don't need it)
4774875 1 : 2 : 3
4944839 1 : 2 : 3
5245283 1 : 2 : 3
5268774 1 : 2 : 3
5268813 1 : 2 : 3
```

Comment: That looks like it would work. How would i then get the dates into different columns?

Comment: You need a pivot to do that. Not this method

Comment: @tithij Google it you will find plenty.